# View the messages published to ejabberd xmpp nodes

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, agsxmpp

I have an ejabberd xmpp pubsub server and I'd like to view the messages that have been published to specific nodes. Is there a way to accomplish this within the web admin; if not, how? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to view pubsub node activity from the web admin, but ejabberd does have a ejabberd-message-archiving module and that may allow it.

You could create a bot or other piece of code that is subscribed to the nodes you want to track and have it create a web viewable archive.